# webkit - css styling not working

Tags: css, magento

The selection button as shown in the image below is not showing in my css set up for the select option of the website.

http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/nl/frames/aventon-frames/aventon-cordoba-frameset-wit

Select option without the button:
[image: Selector without button]
Select option with button:

[image: Selector with button]

Button that is missing:

[image]

Here is the CSS code for the option:

```
product-options dd select {
width: 100%;
border: 2px solid #aab2bd;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
width: 100%;
border: 2px solid #aab2bd;
color: #666;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 9px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #999;
-webkit-appearance: none;
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A way I've seen custom dropdowns done before is by using the little drop caret as a `background-image` with a `background-position` value of whatever puts it in the right place for your design.

Have a look at the pages linked below.

[Background-image attribute W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)
[Background-position attribute W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)